# Fixed point iteration for finding roots in a system of equations and effect of parameter scaling

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, numerical-methods, roots, fixed-point-theorems

Assume I have a system of three equations

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{-x_1}{1+x_1-b_1} + \ln \left( 1+x_1-b_1 \right) = \frac{y}{a_1}\\
\frac{-x_2}{1+x_2-b_2} + \ln \left( 1+x_2-b_2 \right) = \frac{y}{a_2}\\
\frac{a_1}{1+x_1-b_1} + \frac{a_2}{1+x_2-b_2} = y
\end{cases}$$

We know that $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ are all positive real numbers which are our know constants ($a_1,a_2$ are arbitrary and can be adjusted, more explanation at the bottom of the page). Also
$x_1,x_2,y \in \mathbb{R}^+$ are our variables. We know $x_1-b_1 \ge 0$, $x_2-b_2 \ge 0$, $1-b_1 \le 0$ and $1-b_2 \le 0$ always holds true.

It can be shown that $x_1,x_2$ can be solved like this

$$\begin{cases}
x_1 = \exp \left( W_0\left( -(1-b_1)e^{-(1+\frac{y}{a_1})} \right) +1 + \frac{y}{a_1} \right) - (1-b_1) \\
x_2 = \exp \left( W_0\left( -(1-b_2)e^{-(1+\frac{y}{a_2})} \right) +1 + \frac{y}{a_2} \right) - (1-b_2)
\end{cases}$$

Where $W_0$ is the zeroth vranch of Lambert_W function. Then we substitute $x_1,x_2$ in the third equation to get this natural recursion

$$f(y) = \\ \frac{a_1}{\exp \left( W_0\left( -(1-b_1)e^{-(1+\frac{y}{a_1})} \right) +1 + \frac{y}{a_1} \right)} + \frac{a_2}{\exp \left( W_0\left( -(1-b_2)e^{-(1+\frac{y}{a_2})} \right) +1 + \frac{y}{a_2} \right)} \\ = y$$

I want to solve this last equation using the fixed point iteration and first guess $y^0 \ge 0$ (I omitted the proof that root is unique and always exist, just take derivative and check function at zero and infinity, since the function is continuous). For a fixed point iteration $f(y)=y$ to converge to the root, the sufficient condition is that $|f'(y)|\le 1$. Now we calculate the derivative (for Lambert-W, $\frac{dW(z)}{dz} = \frac{W(z)}{z(1+W(z))}$)

$$f'(y) = \frac{-1}{\exp \left( W_0\left( -(1-b_1)e^{-(1+\frac{y}{a_1})} \right) +1 + \frac{y}{a_1} \right)\left( 1+W_0\left( -(1-b_1)e^{-(1+\frac{y}{a_1})} \right) \right)} + \\ \frac{-1}{\exp \left( W_0\left( -(1-b_2)e^{-(1+\frac{y}{a_2})} \right) +1 + \frac{y}{a_2} \right)\left( 1+W_0\left( -(1-b_2)e^{-(1+\frac{y}{a_2})} \right) \right)}$$

As it can be seen, we always have $f'(y)\le 0$. Also $\lim_{y\to\infty}f(y) = 0$. Therefore if $|f'(0)|\le 1$ then the fixed point iteration always converges but unfortunately

$$|f'(0)| =  \frac{1}{\exp \left( W_0\left( -(1-b_1)e^{-1} \right) +1\right)\left( 1+W_0\left( -(1-b_1)e^{-1} \right) \right)} + \\ \frac{1}{\exp \left( W_0\left( -(1-b_2)e^{-1} \right) +1 \right)\left( 1+W_0\left( -(1-b_2)e^{-1} \right) \right)}$$

Which means $|f'(0)|\le 1$ is not always true necesssary.

============>  My question is  <============

-How can I guarantee the convergence of fixed point iteration?

-The parameters $a_1,a_2$ are arbitrary, in the sense that I can scale them with a positive factor, for example $\beta \ge 0$, $(a_1,a_2) \Rightarrow (\beta a_1,\beta a_2)$ can be substituted. I also calculated $\frac{\partial f'(y)}{\partial a_i}, i \in {1,2}$ and found out that $f'(y)$ is a decreasing function of $a_1,a_2$. Can I scale $a_1,a_2$ to guarantee convergence? Please notice that at origin, i.e. $f(0)$, dependency on $a_1,a_2$ vanishes.

Any help, hint, clue would be appreciated!

Comment: I don not think that scaling could change the problem. Writing the problem as $g(y)=0$ and using Newton method, more important would be to select a $y_0$ such that $g(y_0)\times g''(y_0) >0$ (Darboux theorem).

Comment: Claude Leibovici, thank you for the information. I want to use fixed point, because it occurred naturally and to use Newton's method, you have to work more for your meal, with fixed point it's just plug the guess and calculate. Can you please elaborate why do you think scaling won't work?

Comment: I did not say that it will not work; just that I do not think that this will change the problem. By the way, Newton is a fixed point method.